# how to add location constraints for an object in blender?

Tags: python, blender

I want to make it so that my program will stop running and print object is out of bounds if an object goes say into the negative z part of the plane in blender.
the objects name is Cube.031. I will sudo code what I want to do I just am not sure about sure how to do the syntax for it.

```
 if(Cube.031.zLocation < 0)
        print(object is out of bounds)
        end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know some programming, [learning python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) won't take long.

For the blender specific info, almost everything is accessed through the `bpy` module, the [API reference is online](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/contents.html).

You can refer to an object by name in `bpy.data.objects[]`. There are also other lists available, like `bpy.context.selected_objects[]` and `bpy.context.visible_objects[]`.

An objects [location](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.location) is an array of three values (x,y,z), you can either access the z location as `location.z` or `location[2]`.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube.031']

if obj.location.z < 0:
    print('object is out of bounds')
```

If you wanted to go through all selected objects

```
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if obj.location.z < 0:
        print('object {} is out of bounds'.format(obj.name))
```

Note that v2.80 is due for release soon and has some changes to the [API](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/), if you are just starting with blender you may want to start with 2.80. You will also find [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com) a better place to ask for blender specific help.